# Outlook Email User Interface (UI) Customization display like Tab or mobile

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-addin

I have requirement of outlook( desktop application)  view customization . My requirement is when i click on Email  item then Email list should be hidden and again if i click on back button of reading pane mail list should be displayed  to user in sliding manner (slide effect like Apple Tab (slide in Slide Out Effect in mail app )) please suggest me any tool , interface , customization third party application , or Visual studio app.

please suggest as early as possible.

thanks in advance

Rohit

Comment: Please suggest for any version of Outlook . like 2007, 2010, 2013, etc

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately want you want to do is impossible.  Outlook views always require a list of items to be displayed (whether it's a Table, Card, List view, etc.).  The only UI elements you can control are the Reading Pane and the Folder Pane.

Comment: Hello Eric thank you  for Replaying me on this, can we give collapsible Effect like Ribbon menu to Mail List ? I want Mail list to be collapsed when i click on any mail item after collapsing mail list Reading pane should be displayed and when i again click to some Back  or close button mail list will be displayed with collapsible effect (scrolling from left to right) .

Comment: i have Video of the same how can i post this here ..??

Comment: Eric Legault can you please provide me link or any article regarding Outlook View and its Structure.

Comment: You cannot collapse the email list - it is impossible. If you want to show/hide the Reading or Folder Panes, use the Explorer.ShowPane method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863893.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customize the built-in UI. The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. As a workaround you can develop an adjacent Outlook window where you can display whatever you need. See [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/) for more information.